# Force on Neodymium Magnet due to Magnetic Field from Electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, research-level

I am a mechanical engineer currently in a university research program, and my project involves mixing bonded neodymium powder (Magnequench for those who are interested) into a polymer in order to cheaply magnetize the polymer, and then move it around using an electromagnetic probe. I am trying to model the forces on the powder, or at least get an extremely rough approximation of what they might be, using ANSYS and some assumptions.

My issue is that I can't seem to find formulas online for what the forces on the powder due to the electromagnet would be, or even any force on a ferromagnet due to an external field. I'm assuming that the powder would be similar to ferromagnetic materials, meaning they would have a magnetic moment, but then there are never any properties given that could give me that information, as far as I can tell. I've been lost in research for a few hours now looking at different things and I'm lost. Does anyone know anything about this? Am I even asking the right questions?

Here is the property sheet for the powder if it helps:

https://mqitechnology.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/mqp-15-7-20065-070.pdf

Comment: Is  properties of magnetic rubber what are you looking for?